# Multiple queries in mysql to the information schema

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL and I would like to know if I make multiple select statements simultaneously in order to get information from the information schema, how are these queries handled? Could this cause some potential database malfunction?

Comment: How would you present them to the database simultaneously?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629979/nested-select-statement-in-sql-server

Comment: @mort: we may have multiple clients using the information schema. By simultaneously I mean, one client can run a select query and before this ends another one runs select. will this result in a mess? thank you for your time

Comment: @nha: I checked, and we are not asking the same thing, unfortunately

Comment: @Alex you mean different clients on different machines ?

Comment: @nha: I mean different programs running on the same server. Each program plays with his own database, but may ask the information schema (I guess you call this master database?) about tables existing in his database. My question is: if two programs ask the information schema concurrently, if there can be a potential problem.

Comment: sure there is a potential problem. forbid it from happening if it really matters

Comment: @Alex the database will handle concurrent transactions, depending on the query/engine. For instance have a look at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22321/mysql-transaction-vs-lock

Comment: thank you guys. The query for the information schema is just a select query, and the engine is MyISAM (as far as I can tell). Is this bad or good news?

Comment: Well I'm no database expert but InnoDB could be a good pick : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb, otherwise for your SELECT statements, have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415195/myisam-place-table-lock-on-table-even-when-dealing-with-select-query

Comment: perhaps you are not a database expert, but you were really helpful. thank you very much

Comment: @Alex I am glad it was helpful. If that answered your question, then please accept the answer I just wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your are using the `myISAM` storage engine and are worrying about [concurrent `SELECT` statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415195/myisam-place-table-lock-on-table-even-when-dealing-with-select-query):

`READ` (`SELECT`) can happen concurrently as long as there is no `WRITE` (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` or `ALTER TABLE`). Ie. you can have either one writer or several readers.

Otherwise the operations are queued and executed as soon as possible.
There is a special case : [concurrent inserts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/concurrent-inserts.html).

**Note** : if you are wondering about the choice between the two main mySQL storage engines `myISAM` and `InnoDB`, `InnoDB` is usually a good choice, please read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb).